# Delete files from Server 2003 network share

Tags: windows-server-2003

Our company has a shared network folder that employees can scan documents into via printer/scanners. The printer/scanner uses a network account to put the scanned document image into the shared folder.

This has worked well for the most part, but now I'm bumping into two users being unable to delete or rename the scanned files. All our users are administrator accounts, both on the domain and on their local machines. Additionally, both users have explicit full privileges to the files and their containing folders, up to the root of the share.

Whenever they try to delete or rename a file, they receive a "File Access Denied: You need permission from [domain]\[scanning network account] to perform this action."

It almost seems like they're being treated as basic user accounts instead of administrator accounts, but they are definitely admin accounts.

I've checked everywhere I know to check, and these users have the exact same privileges and access rights as other users who can manipulate the files with no issues.

Any ideas what might be causing the issues?

Comment: All of the users are **domain** admins?!?!  Local admin is bad enough, but every user as domain admin is practically begging to have issues.  I would stop worrying about file permissions and fix that first.

Comment: Being an administrator doesn't proffer NTFS permissions to files and folders. Have you verified that the user accounts for these users have the appropriate NTFS permissions on the files and folders in question?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, they have NTFS permissions on both the individual files and their containing folders.

Comment: @Grant Sadly, I don't have a say in this. The way our system has been set up since long before I got here, the programs that we run use domain admin access to accomplish their tasks. Changing that would be a monumental restructuring -- far beyond our two-man IT capabilities :-(

Comment: @AnthonyFisher its even scarrier that your previous question says you work for a bank.  Hope nobody ever learns they can install the AD management tools on their desktop...